# Hiding New Folder Command for specific users

Tags: sharepoint-online, folder, authorization

The image below shows a way to disable Folder creation for the entire Document Library. Is there a way to limit this functionality to specific users / groups?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default, we can't control the permission for this feature.

As a workaround, we can use JavaScript code to achieve it. Check if the current user in the limit user array, and hide the New Folder using CSS style.

The following code for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#RibbonContainer").ready(function (){
    var currentUserId=_spPageContextInfo.userId;
    var limitUserIds=[1,3];  
    if($.inArray(currentUserId, limitUserIds)!=-1){
        $("head").append("<style>a[id='Ribbon.Documents.New.NewFolder-Large']{display:none;}</style>");
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: That's great, but what about the Modern experience?

Comment: For modern experience, you can use an SPFx Application Customizer to add JavaScript (e.g. header) to every page in a site. https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/06/SPFx-Application-Customizer-Global-JS-Page-Header.html

Comment: so are you hard coding the user Ids in your code? I'm assuming they wouldn't be single ints.

Comment: You can get all the user's Id from a group using REST API, or check if the current user in the group or not.